# Simplify this condition

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements

```
a = [34,56,23,68]
b = [76,78324,1234]
dict1 = {34:76,56:1234}
for i in dict1:
    if (a,b)!=(i,dict1[i]):
        print('yes')
    else:
        print('no')
```

What does this condition check =>

```
(a,b)!=(i,dict1[i])
```

?
Also, what are the conditions when we will get no as result?

- If key and value present in `dict1` match with a and b list- O/p :
  yes yes
- If key match and value does not it gives - O/p : yes yes
- If key  and value does not match it gives - O/p : yes yes

Comment: This condition will always be `True`. `(a,b)` is a tuple of two lists, while `i` will be the keys of `dict1` (some `int`) and `dict1[i]` the matching values (another single `int`). A tuple of two lists of `int` will never be equal to a tuple of two single `int`, so the condition as a whole will always be `True`.

Comment: Please reformat what you expect. Not really clear.

Comment: @Grismar Thank you , that really helped. Also, could you please tell what are the scenarios when this condition be be False?

Comment: @Hayat I have made some changes , can you please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an answer to the question instead of suggestions what the condition is actually supposed to be given in the other answers:

*How does this condition work => `(a,b)!=(i,dict1[i])`?*

This condition compares a tuple of two lists `a` and `b` with a tuple of two integers being key and value in `dict1` and will be always `True` because a list is not equal to an integer.

*Also, what are the test scenarios we'll get 'no' printed?*

With the understanding of the way the condition works described above you see that there are no test scenarios in which 'no' will be printed.